# Find root project directory for current IEditor in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, directory, project

I need to find the path of current editor's project directory without using IStructuredSelection interface. Any input is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the current `IEditorPart` for the editor you can call:

```java
IEditorInput input = editorPart.getEditorInput();
```

to get the input to the editor. If the editor is editing a file in the workspace (it may not be), then the `IEditorInput` will usually be an instance of `IFileEditorInput` and you can the file being edited with:

```java
IFile file = ((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile();
```

once you have the `IFile` you can get the project with:

```java
IProject project = file.getProject();
```